# Can someone give me simple terms for how to upload a Meteor App to Galaxy?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, galaxy

I have seen the guide meteor gives [here](https://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/deploy-quickstart.html), but i already get confused when it tells me i need to host mongo db separately somewhere else... and i don't even understand what cluster i need to choose from, or anything.completely new to this. The only thing I've done before is Sharepoint framework web parts and using sharepoint lists as a database for powerapps, and I'm trying to progress forward as a developer by creating an app (which i have the basics done) and i want it uploaded live on the internetz :D for the product owner to see in action.

Comment: This is a more likely fit for something like the meteor forums, or the Meteor community slack workspace.

Comment: Still seems you could've answered the question instead of thumbs down and a dead end.

Comment: Wasn't me, I was making that suggestion based on the fact that someone down voted the question.

Comment: It's really not clear how to answer your question. It's hard to imagine that anyone on SO will come up with a better guide for you. In fact, I would argue they shouldn't. Because if they did, then they should just submit a PR to improve the official documentation. If you have specific questions on how to do X, then we can help, but I think you'll need to be more specific. For instance, you said you are confused about hosting mongodb somewhere else. Did you also read their recommendation on how to do that? Did you run into any issues with that?

Comment: Thank you Christian for clarification.

Comment: And yeah I do have a specific issue I can address. Will probably repost as a different question that isn’t vague

Answer (score 0):

It is actually pretty simple. Since you are completely new to this I would recommend a bit more reading on deployments, but here is the watered down version for a hobby app:

1. Create an account on MongoDB Atlas: https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas
2. On Atlas create a free tier cluster: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/tutorial/deploy-free-tier-cluster/ it should match you Galaxy region, for simplicity go with AWS us-east-1
3. Allow access to your DB cluster to everyone, follow this guide and you should see the button for that around there as well: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/tutorial/whitelist-connection-ip-address/
4. Ensure that you have an account on Meteor https://www.meteor.com/sign-up
5. Add the needed settings for your app before you deploy to Galaxy: https://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/deploy-guide.html
6. Deploy to Galaxy using the following command: `DEPLOY_HOSTNAME=galaxy.meteor.com meteor deploy [hostname] --settings path-to-settings.json`
   Now the default deploy creates a container for your app on AWS us-east-1 (same as your MongoDB). If you don't have a custom domain you can use the `meteorapp.com`, so something like this for the hostname: `mydeploy1234.meteorapp.com`
   The app should deploy on the smallest (and cheapest) container and you should have access to the 30 day free trial as well.

That should do it. Just double check that you have allowed access to MongoDB Atlas from everywhere (IP restricted access works only with Galaxy Professional) and that you have set the correct connection string in the settings (these are a common pitfalls).